What is the difference between ausmachen and ausschalten?
Web sites having deviations in illustration between those two verbs.
May some one please tell when to use each?

Ausschalten implies a Schalter (switch) of some kind. Ausmachen can e.g. be used for extinguishing a fire which doesn't have a switch.

In English you can put out a light or put out a fire. You can only switch off a light. "Machen" is a very general verb and can mean almost any action at all; it's more general than "put". But, as you said, "schalten" has the word "Schalter" built in, so it has to involve a switch, though the switch may be figurative.

@RDBury This should be an answer.

Both verbs have meanings, where they can't be substituted by the other, so ausmachen could also mean agree on something and ausschalten can also be used in the abstract sense of disabling something (e.g. adversary anti-missile weapons), which also serves as counter-example to the needs a switch argument.
The verbs containing machen are more frequently found in the colloquial area. For more ideas on the use I recommend the DWDS corpora.

Ausmachen has also another meaning like "cannot figure it out" as in "ich kann das nicht ausmachen". Two distinct sub-cases: (i) if you have something far away and you cannot get a sharp view on it it means only limited ability of your sense to hear/visualize something: "Q: siehst du den Adler da auf der Fahnenstange" "A: Ich kann den nicht ausmachen." (ii) if someone points at some content in a text, sociological context etc, it means you don't consider the aspect to be actually present from a statistical perspective: "Da gibt es bedenkliche marxistische Ströme in der Studentenbewegung." "A: Ich kann das nicht ausmachen."
In addition "ausmachen" is used as "doesn't do much harm" as in "Heute ist es aber frostig." "A: das macht mir nichts aus."
